# Powershell: Using array and gci

Tags: powershell, copy-item

thanks for help in advance. I am new to powershell, so sorry for noobish questions.

Problem: I import a csv with filenames to an array. The array consists out of numbers (i.e. 95325866256) what are filenames. My aim is to copy all files from a remote system with the IDs from the array. Here is what I tried:

```
$array_chipIDs = Import-csv "C:\Data\chipID.csv" -UseCulture
$Export = "C:\Data\Export"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Anzahl der IDs: "$array_chipIDs.count

foreach ($i in $array_chipIDs){
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $i 

 foreach ($chipID in $array_chipIDs) {  
       Get-ChildItem -Path $pfad1 -Recurse -Include *.sdf, *.idat | select FullName | Copy-Item -Path {$_.Fullname} $export  
    if ($chipID -eq ''){
   break
   }
       }
```

But I miss the Point to give the gci the actual array value (the filename).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. You get the IDs from file and you loop through them but the files you are copying are from $pfad1 variable which is not defined anywhere by the way. You are also looping twice without a reason.

If you just want to copy files from one folder to another folder then use this example.

```
 $source = "c:\sourcefolder"
 $destination = "c:\destinationfolder\"
 get-childitem -Recurse $source | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | 
     copy-item -Destination $destination
```

You can define the source and destination folders to be network paths as long as you have permissions on the folders.

Now this will copy any files from source to destination. If you want to restrict particular type or extension of files then we can extend the above.

```
 $source = "c:\sourcefolder"
 $destination = "c:\destinationfolder\"
 $extensions = @("*.sdf","*.idat")
 foreach($e in $extensions){
     get-childitem -Recurse $source -Filter $e | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | 
         copy-item -Destination $destination

}
```

This code will then try and get only the extensions added to the array $extensions. You can add more extensions.

If you want to do it from the file like the excel then may be share a sample. The file must have the correct file name. If it does not have the full path then you need to define the actual path in a variable like source. But can't say much unless you give us an example. Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need `foreach` after `get-childitem`, `copy-item` will gladly take the source paths from the pipeline, so `where { ... } | copy-item -Destination:$destination` will work just fine

Comment: Yea i suspected that. Thanks for clarifying. For some reason i always use foreach that way.

Comment: Thank you for fast and helpful reply.

What I tried is to find and copy the file-names (what are IDs) from the importet csv. So I Import them from the CSV into an array (e.g. 95685245 from the csv is on a remote system file 95685245.sdf)
If done, the gci shall find files with the extensions AND only the ones with the IDs as filename which are importet from the csv. I don't need all the .sdf-files, just the ones from my imported csv file. But I dont get the gci piped the way that it only greps the name from my array in a foreach loop.

Thank you very very much and happy SysAdmins-Day.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now solved the problem by my self. I have forgotten to pick the value from the Array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop was just to check the Import of my csv. But here is now a working foreach-loop.

```
foreach($chipID in $array_chipIDs) {
   Get-ChildItem -Path $s_path -Recurse -Include "filetype" | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match $chipID.ChipID } | Copy-Item -Destination $export
    }
```